# How to retrieve exception that caused a test to fail from MbUnit TestContext

Tags: unit-testing, mbunit

I had a look at TestContext.CurrentContext.Outcome but it doesn't have what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Pawel

Answer (score 2):

The exception object is not stored, although it is possible to extract the stack trace etc from the log (see https://github.com/Gallio/Gallio-VS2011-Integration/blob/master/MbUnitAdapter/MbUnitAdapter/StackTraceHunter.cs).

Probably the best thing to do is subclass TestAttribute:

```
public class InspectExceptionAttribute : TestAttribute
{
    protected override void Execute(PatternTestInstanceState state)
    {
        try
        {
            base.Execute(state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // do something with e
        }
    }
}

public class InspectExceptionTests
{
    [InspectException]
    public void With_interceptor()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Without_interceptor()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think that you could use a try-catch statement to catch the Exception then use it from there

Comment: Then I  would have to do this in every test which is what I'm trying to avoid